# How to assign class level property value to nested object properly through in deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Question: I wanted to assign the value of the employee.name to address.name through deserialization.

Inputs:

```
  var json = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"foo\",\"address\":{\"name\":\"\"}}";
```

Code:

```
  public class Employee  
   {  
     public int Id { get; set; }          
     public string Name { get; set; }  
     public Address Address { get; set; }  
   }  
public class Address  
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}

var employeeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JObject.Parse(json)));
```

I want output would be like that

```
Employee = {
Id = 1,
Name ="foo",
Address = {Name = "foo"}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this looks like a homework problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var json = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"foo\",\"address\":{\"name\":\"\"}}";
var employeeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json);
employeeObject.Address.Name = employeeObject.Name;
```

Once you deserialize the object, you can assign `employeeObject.Address.Name` to `employeeObject.Name`.

Comment: After that you can serialize it back to Json:

   var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeObject);

Comment: Instead of doing employeeObject.Address.Name = employeeObject.Name;

Comment: Could we have another way of doing it like JsonSerializerSettings or anything else

Comment: You could try with a custom JSON converter, but you would still have to parse the object. The usefulness of that approach depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yout don't require `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JObject.Parse`. It should be -

```
var employeeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json);
```

Comment: Yes correct, but I don't want to do employeeObject.Address.Name = employeeObject.Name this step